# JDBC Connection to CA Datacom DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am trying to make a connection to a CA Datacom database from a Spring Java application. I am new to both Spring/Java and Datacom. After doing some searching I have come across a few resources (very few). In these I had and idea of what the connection should be. This is what I have in my application.yml so far for my datasource stuff, and I am not sure if it is right or not (doesn't seem to be):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MyBatchApplication
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:datacom://hostname:hostport/ServerName=xxxx,ApplicationID=xxxx,UserID=xxxx,Password=xxxx
    driver-class-name: ca.datacom.jdbc.DatacomJdbcDriver
```

I do have a jar file that is the driver for Datacom, and am importing that into my project with my build.gradle. I have code in my main project that tests the connection and it works that way. So that code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:datacom://hostname:hostport/ServerName=xxxx,ApplicationID=xxxx,UserID=xxxx,Password=xxxx";

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        if (conn != null) {
            System.out.println("We have a connection");
            conn.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is no connection");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    SpringApplication.run(MyBatchApplication.class, args);
}
```

So the top part there works great. I get the `We have a connection` message. However, once the bottom part runs with the Spring application I get an error saying:

`IO error sending or receiving native data: ca.datacom.db.DBIOException: MAINFRAME SERVER ERROR: REQUESTED SERVER NOT AVAILABLE`

So I am at a loss. I know the server is available, and I know my credentials are correct since it works in the Java, but the Spring connection for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're really asking. You will need to have the necessary driver library on the classpath (that is: you need to specify it in the dependencies in the gradle build file), and you may need to specify the driver class name in the configuration properties.

Comment: I have updated my question a little bit more. My original question was not very well put together. I did figure some of it out, but as my update states for some reason the connection doesn't work in ```SpringApplication.run()``` So that is what I am currently trying to figure out. Thanks!